# TortoiseHg workbench - Commit&push changes of a repo - one subrepo is still in phase "draft" (not puhsed)

Tags: tortoisehg

In Tortoise I have a repo "NIR_BOL" with few subrepos. I made changes in this subrepos and commited them. Then I went to the repo NIR_BOL and commited all changes comming from the subrepos. Normally these changes are pushed automatically to the main repo (PACS_work) and I can see in all subrepos that the changes are in phase public. But not with my subrepo Bol_5. I have to manually push this change. But why? How can I change this?[image]

Comment: No answer? .....